# Update values in model-database using scritps outside Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with the fields `name, email, login, have_purchased`.

To avoid mixing the website code and some backend/analysis code, the `have_purchased` (boolean) value is updated 6 times a day using some scripts on another server, since it takes a lot of time and lot of computation power, that the website should not suffer from.

I'm wondering, if updating values in a model database, such as `myapp_model` here, *outside* Django e.g using `pandas.df.to_sql("myapp_model")` can cause some damage?

If that is bad idea, what is the best idea when having other scripts running that does not do anything but update the values of the model?

Comment: You may run into locking issues if you are also *writing* to the same table from Django and you should be careful about caching. Other than that it's fine.

Comment: Exactly - I am nervous about the writing issues. Is there a way to overcome this? e.g how is this usually done?